# How I get TextView onClickListener working?

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener, textview

I lost 3 days trying to figure out how I get `TextView` `onClickListener` working in my code.  I tried different ways, I read a lot of solution here in Stackflow but none seemed to fit my code. I almost find a solution, but still doesn't work. I'm a student and a mentor of mine suggested me to add the code on the Array, and so I did.

In my app, I want that when `TextView` with `id title_song` is clicked, the item `TextView` with `id selecteditem` displays the title_song. title_song is in a ListView, TextView selecteditem is in Layout.

Here's the code:-

```
package com.example.android.myapplication;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import static com.example.android.myapplication.R.id.selecteditem;
import static com.example.android.myapplication.R.id.title_song;


public class SongAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Song> implements View.OnClickListener {

    public SongAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Song> pSongs)  {
        super(context,0, pSongs);
    }

    //**
    // titleSong is displayed in TextView
    // when item TitleSong is clicked in the ListView Song
    //*

    private TextView titleSong;
    private TextView selectedSong;

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        titleSong =(TextView) titleSong.findViewById(R.id.title_song);
        selectedSong =(TextView) selectedSong.findViewById(R.id.selecteditem);

        titleSong.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(selectedSong.getId() == R.id.title_song){
                    selectedSong.setText(R.id.title_song);
                }
            }
        });
    }


    //**
    // Provides a view for an AdapterView (ListView, GridView, etc.)
    // @param position The AdapterView position that is requesting a view
    // @param parent The parent ViewGroup that is used for inflation
    // @return The View for the position in the AdapterView

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        // Check if the existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
        View listItemView = convertView;

        if(listItemView == null) {
            listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                    R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        }
        Song local_song = getItem(position);

        TextView titleTextView = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(title_song);
        titleTextView.setText(local_song.getTitleSong());

        TextView artistTextView = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.artist_song);
        artistTextView.setText(local_song.getArtistSong());

        return listItemView;
    }

}
```

For sure, I did a lot of mistakes, the first one is that `setText` is not correct for the goal I want to reach, and I know it, but it is the most similar that I know.

Comment: I do not see setOnClickListener(this) being invoked on the textview. Do you have that code somewhere. Post the complete code

Comment: Set listener inside getView . And look for Custom list view tutorials .

Comment: Why `TextViews` with id `title_song` and `selecteditem` are in Adapter?  What is inside your activity/fragment? Explain your queries with your designs.

Answer (score 0):

Use these

```
 all = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.viewall);
 pdf = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.pic);
```

in on create and then set

all.setOnclickListener(this) in oncreate() method too.Implement onClicklistener when it will show error. it will work like a charm.

**Edited**

```
TextView btn=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.accInfo);
btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //DO you work here
        }
    });
```

**Setting Clicklistenner to TextView will automatically make it clickable so no need of**

```
android:clickable="true"
```